# Use sed to escape a pattern to another sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

I would like an approach to do a replace using the sed command that escapes a "pattern" (string) to be used in another sed command. **This escape process must include handling for multi-line strings pattern.**

To illustrate I present the code below. It works perfectly (well tested so far), but fails when we have strings with multiple lines (see "STRING_TO_ESCAPE").

```
#!/bin/bash

# Escape TARGET_STRING.
read -r -d '' STRING_TO_ESCAPE <<'HEREDOC'
    $N = "magic_quotes_gpc = <b>"._("On")."</b>";
    $D = _("Increase your server security by setting magic_quotes_gpc to 'on'. PHP will escape all quotes in strings in this case."); 
    $S = _("Search for 'magic_quotes_gpc' in your php.ini and set it to 'On'."); 
    $R = ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'); 
    $M = TRUE;
    $this->config_checks[] = array("NAME" => $N , "DESC" => $D , "RESULT" => $R , "SOLUTION" => $S , "MUST" => $M );
HEREDOC
ESCAPED_STRING=$(echo "'${STRING_TO_ESCAPE}'" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g')
ESCAPED_STRING=${ESCAPED_STRING%?}
TARGET_STRING=${ESCAPED_STRING#?}

# NOTE: The single quotes in "'${STRING_TO_ESCAPE}'" serve to prevent spaces 
# being "lost" at the beginning and end of the string! The manipulations with 
# "ESCAPED_STRING" are used to remove them. When we use sed with the file being 
# input (flag "-i") this problem does not occur.

# Escape REPLACE_STRING.
read -r -d '' STRING_TO_ESCAPE <<'HEREDOC'
    /* NOTE: "Magic_quotes_gpc" is no longer required. We taught GOsa2 to deal with it (see /usr/share/gosa/html/main.php). By Questor */
    /* Automatic quoting must be turned on */
    /* $N = "magic_quotes_gpc = <b>"._("On")."</b>";
    $D = _("Increase your server security by setting magic_quotes_gpc to 'on'. PHP will escape all quotes in strings in this case."); 
    $S = _("Search for 'magic_quotes_gpc' in your php.ini and set it to 'On'."); 
    $R = ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'); 
    $M = TRUE;
    $this->config_checks[] = array("NAME" => $N , "DESC" => $D , "RESULT" => $R , "SOLUTION" => $S , "MUST" => $M ); */
HEREDOC
ESCAPED_STRING=$(echo "'${STRING_TO_ESCAPE}'" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g')
ESCAPED_STRING=${ESCAPED_STRING%?}
REPLACE_STRING=${ESCAPED_STRING#?}

# Do the replace.
STRING_TO_MODIFY=$(cat file_name.txt)
MODIFIED_STRING=$(echo "'${STRING_TO_MODIFY}'" | sed 's/$TARGET_STRING/$REPLACE_STRING/g')
MODIFIED_STRING=${MODIFIED_STRING%?}
MODIFIED_STRING=${MODIFIED_STRING#?}

echo "$MODIFIED_STRING"
```

Thanks! =D

Comment: This looks like it would be far easier to accomplish with `patch` instead of `sed`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you want to accomplish. *How* do you want to use the escaped string in the second `sed` command?  Are you saying that you want a way to detect literal matches to the original string?

Comment: @John Bollinger I'll try to clarify. What I want is to be able to use in the pathern of a sed a string that originally had multiple lines. What I want is a pathern sed that escapes this string with multiple lines to be used in another sed. Example: `ESCAPED_STRING=$(echo "'${STRING_TO_ESCAPE}'" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g')`

Comment: Yes, @EduardoLucio, I saw that already in your example code.  As far as I can tell, that seems to be the `sed`-based mechanism you are using now to perform the escaping.  I'm asking about how you want to use the *result* of that, or of whatever alternative we might suggest.  As the answer I've already written describes, I suspect that your problem is not so much with the escaping at all, but rather with the `sed` program in which you are using the result.

Comment: This question seems hard to follow.  Please provide an example input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **This escape process must include handling for multi-line strings pattern.**

I think you're barking up the wrong tree.  If you're trying to match a multiline pattern then the most significant problem is not how to escape the pattern, but rather how to write a `sed` script that will successfully match anything to it.

The problem is that `sed` reads input one line at a time.  There are various ways to collect multiple lines and to operate on such collections, but you need to do that explicitly in the program.  `sed` is therefore a poor choice for attempting to match arbitrary multiline text.  To make your task feasible, you would want to know how many lines the pattern will contain, so as to write your `sed` program to be specific for that.  Even then, this might be a better job for Perl.

**Update:**

Because I like `sed`, however, here's an example of how you could write a `sed` program that matches multiline patterns:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
# Build up a three-line window in the pattern space
:a
/\(.*\
\)\{2\}/! { N; ba; }

# A(nother) multiline pattern.  If the pattern fails to match then the
# first line of the pattern space is printed and deleted, then
# we loop back to reload.
/^The\
quick\
brown$/! { P; D; ba; }

# Do whatever we want to do in the event of a match
s/brown/red/

# If control reaches here then the whole pattern space is printed,
# and if any input lines remain then we start again from the beginning
# with an initially-empty pattern space.
```

Example input:

```
$ ./ml.sed <<EOF
The
quick
brown
fox          
jumped over
the lazy dog.
EOF
```

Output:

```
The
quick
red
fox
jumped over
the lazy dog.
```

Note well that newlines are matched as ordinary characters, but that literal newlines in pattern or replacement text need to be escaped in the normal way, for syntactic reasons.

**Update 2**:

Here's a variation the replaces appearances of the three-line sequence

```
brown
fox          
jumped over
```

with the three-line sequence

```
red
pig          
is fat
```

. Of course there are many other ways to accomplish the same thing with `sed`, and one of the others might be preferable to this for your particular purposes.

```
#!/bin/sed -f
:a
/\(.*\
\)\{2\}/! { N; ba; }

/^brown\
fox\
jumped over$/! { P; D; ba; }

s/.*/red\
pig\
is fat/
```

Comment: "Even then, this might be a better job for Perl." -> Excellent answer! You could then provide an example with perl (or awk), because if there is no escaping then we should consider another alternative. I can update the question if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused by this last example. Where is the multiline pattern? I explain better ... If my input is `The
quick
brown
fox
jumped over
the lazy dog.` so I imagine that the multiline pattern would be something like `brown
fox
jumped over` and replace would be something like `brown
pig
jumped over`. Maybe I did not get it right. If you can explain better... Thanks! =D

Comment: @EduardoLucio, there are *two* multiline patterns in the example, a two-line pattern spanning physical lines 4-5 (but that matches three-line groupings because of the quantifier within), and a three-line pattern spanning physical lines 10-12.  The latter matches, at once, the first three lines of the input.  Only one of those lines is then changed, but any arbitrary `sed` action(s) could have been taken, such as replacing them with something completely different.

Comment: The key thing the example demonstrates, though, is not the multiline patterns themselves, but rather a way to get multiple lines into the pattern space at the same time, so as to be able to successfully match multi-line patterns at all.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding =D . But, with the example presented by you I could do the following replace: input is `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.` the multiline pattern is `brown fox jumped over` and replace is `red pig is fat`? If yes, I could generalize your script case to anyone else. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @EduardoLucio, the example could be modified to do what you describe.  Again, the most fundamental point is that `sed` can match multiple input lines at once only if it has multiple input lines in its pattern space at the same time, and you have to explicitly provide for that in your `sed` program if you want it.  If you're going to do this then I strongly recommend that you study a `sed` manual, because I don't think you'll easily achieve your particular intended result by cutting / pasting / modifying bits and pieces from examples.

Comment: I do not want to explore your goodwill... =D But could you provide an example as I proposed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Very well, @EduardoLucio, I have added a variation on the existing example that performs the alternative substitution you requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're the best! =D